# Using Database Variables for PHP Template Engine

Tags: php, templates, template-engine

So i wrote a template engine and it works, but i need help adding a feature to it. Here is the code for the main part:

```
public function parseFileContents($contents, array $values){
        foreach($values as $key => $replacement){
            $key = "[$key]";
            $contents = str_replace($key, $replacement, $contents);
        }
        return $contents;
         }
```

What happens is i put the values that need to be changed and what it needs to be changed to in an array and sort through the file replacing whatever is in the array with whatever is in the file. What I want to do is have a certain number of places in the file that match a number of items in a database. Here's what i mean:

```
<select id="inputHeader" name="itemHeader">
    <option value="[Header0]">[Header0]</option>
    <option value="[Header1]">[Header1]</option>
    <option value="Header">[Header2]</option>
    <option value="Header">[Header3]</option>
</select>
```

I need the number of options to match the number of headers that will be placed in that slot. Does anyone have any ideas on how this could work?

Answer (score 0):

In the popular template engines the variables are still fetched from the db and then sent to the template engine. You cannot avoid iteration through the fetched result.
i.e. fetching an array $array with variable $header, indexed with "i" should be:

```
  <option value="[$array[i].header]">[$array[i].header]</option>
```

But ain't sure if the way with [] will work. Maybe you should youse } {  -> {$array[i].header}